# Unable to view Hystrix metrics in Dropwizard app via hystrix-metrics-event-stream servlet

Tags: java, dropwizard, hystrix

I have a Dropwizard 0.8.1 app to which I have added a number of `HystrixCommand` classes for calling out to various external services. I now want to visualize stats related to calls to those services, but I can't seem to get my app to play nice with the [Hystrix Dashboard](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Dashboard). All the documentation seems to imply that if I get the `hystrix-metrics-event-stream` servlet working in my app then everything should Just Work, but when I call my servlet endpoint directly (`curl  http://localhost:8080/hystrix.stream`) I just get a long stream of `ping:` lines, implying that there are no metrics available to be published. I have a cron job repeatedly calling my `HystrixCommand` objects to try to generate some stats, to no avail.

Is there something I'm not doing? I have added the dependency to my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.netflix.hystrix</groupId>
    <artifactId>hystrix-metrics-event-stream</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I have integrated the servlet into Dropwizard in `App.java`:

```
public void run(final AppConfig configuration, final Environment environment) throws Exception {
...
environment.getApplicationContext().addServlet("com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.metrics.eventstream.HystrixMetricsStreamServlet", "/hystrix.stream");
```

Is it possible that I need to manually publish metrics data to be picked up by the `HystrixMetricsPoller`? Or maybe I need to tweak some config for my dev environment? Help is appreciated!

Comment: FWIW just in case anyone suggests it, I have looked at [Tenacity](https://github.com/yammer/tenacity) from Yammer, but it seems overly complex for my needs, and shouldn't be required just to use Dropwizard with Hystrix, so I want to solve this problem without integrating a(nother) large third party library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorted it! It turned out that the version of the `hystrix-metrics-event-stream` artifact was 1.4.5 but the version of `hystrix-core` was 1.3.8. I didn't spot it at first because it was stored in another POM file. I'm now using exactly the same version across all hystrix packages and getting data just fine from the `hystrix.stream` servlet.

As a related aside, I also found [hystrix-dropwizard-bundle](https://github.com/zapodot/hystrix-dropwizard-bundle) which looks like a much easier and flexible way to integrate Dropwizard with Hystrix for most people than doing it from scratch or using something as complex as Tenacity. It includes support for `HystrixCodaHaleMetricsPublisher` which might be of use to people using Dropwizard metrics (we're not).